# How to convert a JSON object stream into an array with jq

Tags: json, jq

I want to use `jq` to put a stream of json objects into a json array, for example, from

```
{"a":1}
{"b":2}
```

to

```
[{"a":1},
{"b":2}]
```

But this would not work

```
echo '
{"a":1}
{"b":2}
'|jq '[.]'
```

since I got

```
[
  {
    "a": 1
  }
]
[
  {
    "b": 2
  }
]
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Slurp it up with the `-s` option.

```
$ jq -s '.' <<< '{ "a": 1 } { "b": 2 }'
[
  {
    "a": 1
  },
  {
    "b": 2
  }
]
```

As another option, reading the values using `inputs` is a much more flexible alternative.  You'll usually want to use this in conjunction with the `-n` option to prevent the first value from being consumed prematurely.

```
$ jq -n '[inputs]' <<< '{ "a": 1 } { "b": 2 }'
```

Comment: I have a slight variation of this. My inputs are arrays `[{"a":1}]` and `[{"b":2}]` and the result should be without the inner arrays, ie. `[{"a":1},{"b":2}]`. Any tipp? It seems some concepts of jq are still eluding me.

Comment: @towi you could `flatten` the slurped inputs `jq -s 'flatten'`. Or better, iterate over each the inputs `jq -n '[inputs[]]'`

Comment: `flatten` was the hint I needed. But I first had to understand the concept, that `jq` no just reads _one_ JSON entity but accepts a "stream" of them. With that I understood `-s` and with that I understood `flatten`. :-)