# Building valid JSON playlist from directory of files using MediaInfo Command Line and jq

Tags: json, jq, mediainfo

I'm using MediaInfo command line v18.08 on ubuntu to parse multiple files in a directory and output JSON, like this: `mediainfo * --output=JSON`

Which outputs the following JSON for each file (trimmed down a bit)

```
{
    "media": {
        "@ref": "openingmusic.mp3",
        "track": [
            {
                "@type": "General",
                "Duration": "17.789",
                "Encoded_Library": "LAME3.98r"
            },
            {
                "@type": "Audio",
                "Format": "MPEG Audio",
                "Encoded_Library_Settings": "-m s -V 2 -q 3 -lowpass 18.6 --vbr-old -b 32"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But I only want a subset of that JSON, so I used jq-1.5-1

`mediainfo *.mp3 --output=JSON |  jq '. | {duration: .media.track[0].Duration, pubDate: .media.track[0].File_Modified_Date_Local, url: .media."@ref"}'`

Great, except there's no `,` between the elements, the whole lot isn't wrapped in [], and of course, while I can fudge that part, if I join the output, I get a trailing comma.

What's the proper jq way of doing this, please?

Comment: It appears `mediainfo` is outputting json per mp3 file. They are separate and distinct objects. You'd have to slurp the input in first if you want to treat the outputs as a single array (or collect the `inputs` in an array). Then you can map out the properties. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404575)

Comment: Thanks @JeffMercado - It seems that the version of mediainfo which was released moments after I posted this question (18.08-1 which got updated via apt upgrade) now wraps the results for "*.mp3" in a JSON object so it can be used "as is"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--slurp` option:

> - --slurp/-s:
>     Instead of running the filter for each JSON object in the input, read the entire input stream into a large array and run the filter just once.

combined with a `map` to run your filter on each element of the array: `jq -s 'map({duration: .media.track[0].Duration, pubDate: .media.track[0].File_Modified_Date_Local, url: .media."@ref"})'`

Then the output will still be an array.

Comment: Well, thank you so much - that worked perfectly, for about 20 minutes! Then everything, including my original code, stopped working. It seems that the version of mediainfo which has just been updated today (18.08-1 which got updated via apt upgrade) now wraps the results for "*.mp3" in a JSON object so it can be used "as is". Although, I do at least know this can be "unwrapped" via jq.
Thanks again.