# Using jq to get the nth element of a stream of JSON entities

Tags: json, select, stream, jq

I have the following json file and I would like access the nth element in it.

```
$ cat a.json
{"one":1}
{"two":2}
{"three":3}
```

Here, the json file is in disassembled form. When I try

```
$ jq '.[0]' a.json
```

I get the error`jq: error (at a.json:1): Cannot index object with number`. The expected output is `{"one":1}`.

Comment: Your input is _not_ an array of objects, therefore you can't access with the `.[0]` notation

Comment: Is there any other way I could access it? @Inian

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a JSON object stream into an array with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404575/how-to-convert-a-json-object-stream-into-an-array-with-jq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is not an array of objects, therefore you can't access with the `.[0]` notation. You could slurp the whole input with `-s`, but you can also use `inputs` with `-n` (null input mode) and get the nth element by specifying the index, i.e to get element at index 2

```sh
# doesn't support negative indices
jq -n '[inputs] | nth(2)' a.json 

# supports negative indices, i.e. [-1] will get the last element  
jq -n '[inputs][2]' a.json
```

Comment: Note that using [inputs] is equivalent to slurping, so this approach is suboptimal and possibly very inefficient.

Comment: @peak: agreed. I'll leave it to the OP to decide on the best solution, AFAIK, it doesn't appear to be a streaming input

Comment: Not sure what your mean by "it doesn't appear to be a streaming input", as the Q and your answer both contend that the input is a stream of JSON entities, which is the relevant concept here, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

jq has a built-in filter, `nth($n; s)` for solving this type of problem very efficiently.  For example, to emit the second item, you would simply invoke:

```
jq -n 'nth(1; inputs)' a.json
```

Note that counting of the items starts from 0.

Efficiency is achieved by avoiding any "slurping" (whether by using the -s option, or by using `[inputs]`), and by stopping once the requested item has been read.