# Convert JSON Objects to JSON object array Without programming Language (exception shell scripting)

Tags: json, excel, bash, shell, excel-import

I have file containing Multiple JSON Objects and need to covert them to JSON. I have bash and Excel installed, but cannot install any other tool.

```
{"name": "a","age":"17"}
{"name":"b","age":"18"}
```

To:

```
[{"name": "a","age":"17"},
{"name":"b","age":"18"}]
```

Comment: is jq an option?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404575/how-to-convert-a-json-object-stream-into-an-array-with-jq

Comment: @SimpleNiko no programming lang and in windows env.

Comment: With programming language is a piece of cake. Help us to understand you. #1 You have an excel with a json text in a cell? #2 As I know, json does not support json as object, so for excel this cell is just a text. If it is a text, why don't add manually (because you don't want a programming language) or with a excel function, the `[ ]` to convert it to an array? #3 Maybe your approach could be improved. What is your real requirement? Bulk the excel on a database? Create a web using the excel?, etc

Comment: What about `sed`, is that optional?

Comment: The notion of "without programming language" is very abstract. Pretty much everything that runs in your computer was built from a programming language. Not to mention Bash itself qualifies as a programming language, thus it doesn’t make any sense to allow Bash and reject programming languages at the same time.

Comment: Perhaps what you mean is "I have `bash` and Excel installed, but cannot install any other tool."

Comment: @chepner you are right.Plus I have many file and all do not have same structure(key value)pair so it should be dynamic

Answer (score 2):

Assuming one object per line as shown by OP question

```
echo -n "["; while read line; do echo "${line},"; done < <(cat test.txt) | sed -re '$ s/(.*),/\1]/'
```

Result:

```
[{"name": "a","age":"17"},
{"name":"b","age":"18"}]
```

Comment: If you're going to use `sed`, you don't need the `bash` loop. `sed '1s/^/[/;2,$s/^/,/;$s/$/]/'` will suffice.

Comment: Thanks @chepner :-) looks easy now that you show it. I'm not that fluent with `sed`

Comment: does it work for any file structure(any number of key value pair)

Comment: Yes, as long as the object is in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by https://askubuntu.com/a/475804

```sh
awk '(NR==FNR){count++} (NR!=FNR){ if (FNR==1) printf("["); printf("%s", $0); print (FNR==count)?"]":"," } END {if (count==0) print "[]"}' file file
```

A less compact but more readable version:

```c
awk '
  (NR==FNR) {
    count++;
  }
  (NR!=FNR) {
    if (FNR==1)
      printf("[");
    printf("%s", $0);
    if (FNR==count)
      print "]";
    else
      print ",";
  }
  END {
    if (count==0) print "[]";
  }' file file
```

The trick is to give the same file twice to `awk`. Because `NR==FNR` is always true for the first file, there is a first parse dedicated to counting the number of lines into variable `count`.

The second parse with `NR!=FNR` will apply the following algorithm for each line:

- Write `[` for the first line only
- Then write the record, using `printf` instead of `print` in order to avoid the newline ending
- Then write either `]` or `,` depending on whether we are on the last line or not, using `print` in order to end with a newline

The `END` command is just a failsafe to output an empty array in case the file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- no requirement to (re)format the input data

Sample input:

```
$ cat raw.dat
{"name": "a","age":"17"}
{"name":"b","age":"18"}
{"name":"C","age":"23"}
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk 'BEGIN {pfx="["} {printf "%s%s",pfx,$0; pfx=",\n"} END {printf "]\n"}' raw.dat
```

Where:

- for each input line we `printf` the line **without** a terminating linefeed
- for the first line we use a prefix (`pfx`) of `[`
- for subsequent lines the prefix (`pfx`) is set to `,\n` (ie, terminate the **previous** line with `,\n`)
- once the file has been processed we terminate the **last** input line with a `printf "]\n"`
- requires a single pass through the input file

This generates:

```
[{"name": "a","age":"17"},
{"name":"b","age":"18"},
{"name":"C","age":"23"}]
```

---

Making sure @chepner's comment (re: a `sed` solution) isn't lost in the mix:

```
sed '1s/^/[/;2,$s/^/,/;$s/$/]/' raw.dat
```

This generates:

```
[{"name": "a","age":"17"}
,{"name":"b","age":"18"}
,{"name":"C","age":"23"}]
```

**NOTE:** I can remove this if @chepner wants to post this as an answer.